# How can I set up the "make" command when use without a makefile?

Tags: makefile

New guy learning programming with C in ubuntu
Using a hello.c for example
From some video tutorial I saw the teacher can use "make hello" to compile the hello.c without setting up a Makefile in current directory
And the command goes like

```
bash$ make hello 
gcc -g -Wall hello.c -o hello
```

I tried to use make on my own ubuntu 14.04
I installed build-essential and tried out the same hello.c

```
bash$ make hello
cc hello.c -o hello
```

It goes like above
How can I make changes to get -g, -Wall or any other flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What you need

The way `make` works is that it produces *targets* out of *sources* through known *recipes*.

When you write your own *Makefile*, you provide the recipes for it, however, `make` has internal recipes, which can be used. You can list them by `make -p`.

One of the recipes tells `make` how to produce <something> out of <something>.c. When you run `make hello`, `make` checks how to produce *hello*, finds that there is a file *hello.c* and that it knows how to produce *hello* from *hello.c* -- using that internal rule.

Now the rule looks like this.

```
%: %.c
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

and the important part, `$(LINK.c)` looks like this

```
LINK.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

You don't need to understand the syntax at this point, the important thing is, that your `make hello` will be transformed into (some unused variables omitted)

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) hello.c -o hello
```

Now **CC**, **CFLAGS**, **CPPFLAGS** and **LDFLAGS** may be set by `make` (in your case, **CC** is set to "cc" and the rest is not set), but you can override this with your environment variables. What you want is having

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS="-g -Wall"
```

### How to get it

To do that for one command only run:

```
CC=gcc CFLAGS="-g -Wall" make hello
```

---

To do that for one session (until you close your terminal) run

```
export CC=gcc
export CFLAGS="-g -Wall"
```

and then just `make hello` or `make whatever` as long as you want.

---

To do that permanently, set these variables in your `.profile` file (open `~/.profile` (create it if it doesn't exist) and add

```
export CC=gcc
export CFLAGS="-g -Wall"
```

to it. Or just run

```
echo 'export CC=gcc' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export CFLAGS="-g -Wall"' >> ~/.profile
```

In both cases, you need to `source ~/.profile` or start a new terminal. It will work happily ever after.

Answer (score 0):

Make has a [number of implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), which are used in the absence of a Makefile.

The one regarding `.c` files is:

> n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`

This means you can set the environment variables:

- `CC` to set the compiler used;
- `CPPFLAGS` to set the preprocessor flags used (the same would be used e.g. for C++ `.cpp` or Fortran `.F` sources);
- **`CFLAGS` to set the compiler flags used.**

The implicit rule turns the `.c` source file into a `.o` object file, which is then linked to an executable according to another implicit rule:

> n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.

Again, you see the environment variables used.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a little more on how can I know the current CFLAGS value and how can I change it? I'm not familiar with command line yet.

Comment: @user6151648: `echo $CFLAGS` / `export CFLAGS=...` / `man bash`. To make settings permanent, edit `~/.bashrc`. Don't do that until you are more experienced; wrong settings there can render your system next to unusable.